# Does java cache the array reference in a for-loop?

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, foreach

There are similar questions :

Advanced for loop does cache reference because it's using the same iterator instance : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29812538/4087512

Normal for loop does cache *length* : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1208331/4087512

But I'm trying to see if the *reference* is cached in a classic for-loop :

```
for(int i=0; i<someObject.getPrivateArray().length; i++){
    //do something where it's necessary to use i AND getPrivateArray()
}
```

as opposed to :

```
int j=0;
for(int var : someObject.getPrivateArray()){
    //do something with j & var
    j++;
}
```

From the question answered here : [Is there a performance difference between a for loop and a for-each loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256859/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-a-for-loop-and-a-for-each-loop) these 2 would have the same performance on an array declared in a local scope, but will there be an overhead of fetching the array from a different object for the for-loop? It was answered above that the array is actually cached in the foreach loop.

Comment: Compile, disassemble (`javap -c -p`), and check?

Comment: If you know that calling `someObject.getPrivateArray()` is costly, then why not store its value in a local variable and use that variable both in the loop declaration and body?

Comment: @ernest_k well, the answer to that will answer my question. if `for` doesn't cache it and requires me to declare a new local variable, then i wouldn't use `for` at all because `foreach` does that and only calls `someObject.getPrivateArray()` once

Comment: @chrylis it still remains a valid question whether i answer it myself or not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Java has no way of knowing that `someObject.getPrivateArray()` will return the same object at each call.  Therefore, it must call the function at each and every iteration.

Eg)

```
Queue<int[]> queue = ...;

for(int i=0; i<queue.remove().length; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

This is exactly the same pattern of code; only the names have changed, yet it is pretty clear the return value of `queue.remove()` won’t be cached.

---

*Update*

@MattTimmermans points out in a comment that the JVM could possibly in-line the `someObject.getPrivateArray()` call, so that the JVM might be able to determine the same object is being returned each time, and optimize away the call.  This would require:

- `someObject` be final or effectively final
- `getPrivateArray()` be final, so it can be inlined
- `getPrivateArray()` must be side-effect free (or the side effects must be executed anyway)
- the returned value must be `final` so that some other entity can’t modify it, guaranteeing the same value is returned

In this case, the JVM ***might*** optimize the call away and move the fetch out of the loop, so effectively caching the result.  I wouldn’t rely on it, when caching the value yourself is easy to do.

Comment: No... but sometimes yes, if it can figure out how to inline the call to `getPrivateArray()`

Comment: `someObject` would have to be an effectively final local, or a final global, so it can’t change.  `getPrivateArray()` would need to be final, so it can be inlined, would need to not have any side effects, and return a final member so that it can’t be modified by another entity.  If all those ducks are in a row, then yes, the JVM might optimize away the repeated calls and use a cached result.